# How do I remove the header background image in Pixture Reloaded theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm not sure why this is difficult, but how do I remove the default background image in the Pixture Reloaded theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the temp directories and css cache files, selected the theme color again, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For Pixture Reloaded 3.x, I made a subtheme and I added this CSS:

```
#header, #header .header-inner {
    background: mycolor;
    background-color: mycolor; }
```

Comment: To what CSS file?  When I change the colors.css file, the changes don't take effect.

Comment: If you made a subtheme, you should add this line to the subtheme.css file in the css directory of the subtheme.

Comment: I'm using the Pixture Reloaded theme.

Comment: Ok.  In that case you can add/modify the pixture_reloaded.css file in the CSS directory.  However, since you're not using a subtheme, you will have to make this change every time you update the theme to a new version.

Comment: I did that originally, and that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you clear the cache after saving changes?

Comment: Religiously.  The file ends up in sites/default/files/color/pixture_reloaded-(some unique val)/colors.css.

Comment: Any ideas how I remove it??